# Does let exist in rxjs6?

Tags: rxjs6

let is something that existed in the past can see it [here in action](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/let.html)

I don't see it in either rxjs or rxjs/operators

nor do I see it inside what appears to be the [RxJS docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api?query=let)

Assuming it did exist, I figured this would've worked since it's meant to be an observable

```
import {interval, let} from 'rxjs';

interval(1000).pipe(
  let(source => interval(1000))
)
.subscribe(a=>console.log(a));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. With the introduction of `pipe`, `let` is redundant. It's essentially the same as `pipe`, but is limited to a single parameter.

That is, `Observable.prototype.let` is equivalent to [this `pipe` signature](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L282):

```ts
pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
```

In your example, you'd just leave out the `let` call, like this:

```ts
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(1000).pipe(
  source => interval(1000)
)
.subscribe(a => console.log(a));
```

Note, however, that `let` is still available via the v5-style imports if `rxjs-compat` is installed along with `rxjs` v6.